# PHP uploader uploads 1 file only

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a uploader in my page that is design to work from iPad and have 8 upload boxes.

When i upload pictures in the uploader, only one files is saved.

How can i get it to save all the pictures that gets uploaded?

- folder is set to 777.

[The Page](http://www.saartech.co.il/iPad/index3.php)

PHP:

```
<?
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $_key => $_value){
        if($_FILES['file']['size'][$_key] !==0){
            $randomizer = rand(0000000, 9999999);
    $f=$randomizer.$_FILES['file']['name'][$_key];
    echo $f;
    echo "<br>";
    $t=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$_key];
    echo $t;
    echo "<br>";

    //echo $_FILES['file']['size'][$_key]."<br />";
    $file_mb = round(($_FILES["file"]["size"][$_key] / 1048576), 2);
    echo "Size: " . $file_mb . " Mb<br />";
    echo $_FILES['file']['type'][$_key]."<br />";
    if( file_exists($t) ){ move_uploaded_file($t, 'upload/' . $f); }
    //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$_key], "upload"/$_FILES['file']['name'][$_key]);
    echo "ok file";
    echo "<br>";
}
    }
}
?>
<form id="main_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?  for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    echo "<input type=\"file\" name=\"file[]\" /> <br>";
    }
    ?>

    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="image1" /><br /> <br /> <br /> 
<input type="file" name="image2" /><br /> <br /> <br /> 
<input type="file" name="image3" /><br /> <br /> <br /> 
<input type="file" name="image4" /><br /> <br /> <br /> 
<input type="file" name="image5" /><br /> <br /> <br /> 
<input type="file" name="image6" /><br /> <br /> <br /> 
<input type="file" name="image7" /><br /> <br /> <br /> 
<input type="file" name="image8" /><br /> <br /> <br />
```

Comment: is your error reporting turned on? Are you getting any specific error messages ?

Comment: can you do a var_dump of your $_FILES array on the form processing page and see what you get ?

Comment: The HTML you're showing in your code, and the HTMLform output from your PHP is different. Your input name on your files should be `file[]` as your PHP shows. Unless I'm not understanding what your code is exactly.

Comment: How can i turn on error reporting?..preety new to php

Comment: At the start of your file add: error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: @TonalDev As Tim Wasson said, you need to first change all instances of `type="file"` to `type="file[]"`

Comment: Hi, friend i tried your code in local, i am getting all uploaded files.Please check if permission is set for upload folder.

Comment: Permissions are set to 777...weird. ill try the error report and the file[] and report back